# Client application for stackexchange sites

Tags: support, feature-request

Do you know of a client-side application able to read/write to stackexchange sites?

Something like the applications that interact with Twitter using `curl`. Do you know of a similar script or application?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackapps.com/

Comment: Are you looking for something more than a web browser?

Comment: Actually, I seem to remember reading that the API does not offer write, access only read. I am not sure about this and may be wrong but I have also never seen a stackapp that let me post.

Comment: i need such as evoulution for reading pop3, or rading rss, Did stack develop SDK for writing same appl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/), you should have a look there. The various applications already developed using the API can be found on [stackapps.com](http://stackapps.com).

If I remember correctly, the API does not allow you to write, only read but you should have a look in case you find anything helpful.